# Данные за предыдущий месяц с учетом года (как yearweek)

Tags: mysql, дата

Использую условие `WHERE month(date)=month(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month))`. Нужно чтобы еще и учитывался год, но если написать `AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())` в январе с декабрем будет засада, потому что год другой. Как правильно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой способ:

```
select * from table
 where date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month),'%Y%m') = date_format(date,'%Y%m')
```

Правильный способ:

```
select * from table
 where date between date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-01')
            and date_add(last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)),interval "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND)
```

Правильный данный способ потому, что мы не вычисляем никакую функцию от столбца в таблице. При наличии [индекса](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html) на столбце `date` позволяет искать по нему, что во много раз быстрее, чем полный перебор таблицы, при первом способе.