# вывод записей по дате MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. 
Допустим у меня есть таблица с записями: "неважно что", date (DATE).
Нужно вывести все записи за определенный день, месяц, год.
допустим за день так `WHERE date = 2016-12-12`. А за месяц или год? В интернете одна работа с функциями типа DATEADD и тому подобное.

Comment: `date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'`

Comment: А вообще подобных вопросов/ответов море. вот например за месяц http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484446/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-yearweek

Comment: @MIke, empty set, хотя запись существует

Comment: А на тесте все работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8003be/1  так что не знаю что у вас там за данные, в каком типе данных хранится дата. Но не видя ваших данных сказать что у вас не так невозможно

Comment: таблица имеет id (int PK), item (name), date (DATE);

Comment: В примере я именно так и сделал, колонка `d`  типом DATE и оно работает. создайте на sqlfiddle.com пример который НЕ работает ...

Comment: Вы были правы посмотрел через **show warnings**, лишний пробел в дате біл

Comment: @Mike, а between  не включает пределы? толко значения строго больше меньше введенных дат?

Comment: Включает. Если надо явно это регулировать пишите отдельные условия date> and date<